# How do I implament an image slider in background with content running over the top?

Tags: jquery, slider

Does anyone know how to create an image slide slider where you can overlay content, it probably sounds simple but this is what I'm after [Srpout theme theme forest](http://demo.wpbandit.com/sprout/demo/page-layouts/default/)  including the ability to change the slide image? I've tried cycle.js but I can't quite get the to center:

```
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery("#slideshow").cycle({
                    fx: 'fade',
                    pause: 1,
                    speed: 1800,
                    timeout: 3500
                });
            });
```

Html:

```
            <body>

                <div id="header-wrap">

                    <div id="header">

                        <div id="backrgound-slider"><?php get_template_part( 'background', 'slider' ); ?></div>

                        <div id="slideshow" class="bgSlider">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/k2-in-skies.jpg" class="bgimage" width="2000" height="1500" alt="Slide 1">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/k2.jpg" class="bgimage" width="2000" height="1500" alt="Slide 2">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/kunhar-river.jpg" class="bgimage" width="2000" height="1500" alt="Slide 3">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/mitre-peak-baltoro.jpg" class="bgimage" width="2000" height="1500" alt="Slide 4">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/musa-ka-musalla.jpg" class="bgimage" width="2000" height="1500" alt="Slide 5">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/nanga-parbat.jpg" class="bgimage" width="2000" height="1500" alt="Slide 6">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/naran-valley.jpg" class="bgimage" width="2000" height="1500" alt="Slide 7">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/shugran.jpg" class="bgimage" width="2000" height="1500" alt="Slide 8">
                        </div>


                        <div id="title">
                            <h1 id="logo">logo</h1>

                            <h2 id="tagline"></h2>

                        </div>

            <!--and so on -->
```

css:

```
                #slideshow, img.bgimage {
                        width: 2000px;
                        height: 640px;
                        position: relative;
                        top: 0;
                        z-index:-9999;
                    left: -500px;
                }
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this [plugin](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! though... I can't seem to get the slides to stop going round even when I put in `slideShow: false` when I click on the next slide the slideshow kicks in again, any ideas?

Comment: can you provide me the code in fiddle?

Comment: Hi Kundan, sorry for the late reply. I've changed from the above to something else as it wasn't quite working out. I now have it apart from when the user clicks to a different page the image goes back to the default image and not the one the user has chosen. I don't know if you know anything about cookies but here's  a link to it on [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZwJe/1/) thanks